# 64bit chroot on 64bit host

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, chroot

The host is a Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit installation.

I'm using `schroot` to run `chroots` for several different Linux systems, such as Ubuntu 10.04 i386. The files for the `chroots` stem from working VirtualBoxes and are rsynced to my host.

This setup works perfectly fine for all i386 `chroots` I have. But Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 does not work. Any command I try to execute via `schroot` reports this:

`E: Failed to execute “some_command”: No such file or directory`

The original system I'm trying to `chroot` into works without problems (in its VirtualBox).
Is there something special that needs to be set-up for 64bit `chroots`?

Again, my host is a 64bit Linux, so this not the usual problem with 32bit hosts trying to chroot into a 64bit installation.

Comment: maybe it is related with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074512/schroot-pass-a-command-to-be-executed-as-if-its-in-a-shell

Comment: nope, I found the problem in the rsync script which fails to sync the /lib64 directory.

Comment: and have you found the solution? if yes, write an answer, please.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write my answer but had to wait for 8 hours or so. And then I forgot. I don't know if that answer is very helpful for anyone else.

Comment: it is the answer for your question, and we don't know if anyone else has the same problem. try to solve your question and mark the response as the correct, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the rsync script did not sync the /lib64 directory to my host. Without it, no command will execute of course.

The lib64 dir contains only one symlink to the ld lib in /lib. But that's one very important symlink.